# is it possible to foreach $this->input->post(); in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I am writing a library for CI and I have a method I call to gather all possible post variables. I would somehow like to leverage the xss and security classes built into the codeigniter input class.

Is that possible?

Here is the working method without any use of the CI input class.

```
private function parse_options()
{  
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val)  
    {  
        $options[$key] = $val;  
    }  

    return $options;      
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not then:

```
private function parse_options()
{  
    foreach($_POST as $key => $val)  
    {  
        $options[$key] = $this->input->post($key);  
    }  

    return $options;      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some 8 years later..

The documentation (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) says this:

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter
$this->input->post(NULL, FALSE); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
```

The reason for trying to only do it the ci-way and not bypassing ci is to keep things uniform. Likely.